# Ansible - construct a new variable by re-grouping based on attribute

Tags: ansible

I have a list of dictionary in Ansible playbook. I want to re-group based on an attribute (in this case, 'team' attribute)  and construct a new variable (dict of list of dict).

```
- name:
    set_fact:
      teams: "{{ teams | default({}) + ..................... }}"

  with_items:
  - {'name': 'john', 'age': 24, 'team': 'team_a'}
  - {'name': 'mary', 'age': 26, 'team': 'team_c'}
  - {'name': 'sam', 'age': 18', 'team': 'team a'}
  - {'name': 'tom', 'age': 20, 'team': 'team b'}
```

I want to construct the variable teams as this format (dict of list of dict):

```
teams: {'team a': [{'john': 24}, {'sam': 18}]
        'team b': [{'tom': 20}]
        'team c': [{'mary': 26}] }
```

Comment: You should fix the data: 1) quotes not balanced ``18'`` 2) underscore ``team_a`` vs ``team a`` 3) ``team_c`` vs `` team c``.

Comment: Are you sure the values of the result should be lists of dictionaries? How do you plan to reference them?

Answer (score 2):

Given the data

```yaml
users:
  - {age: 24, name: john, team: team a}
  - {age: 26, name: mary, team: team c}
  - {age: 18, name: sam, team: team a}
  - {age: 20, name: tom, team: team b}
```

---

Q: ***"Create dictionary"***

```yaml
teams:
  team a: [{john: 24}, {sam: 18}]
  team b: [{tom: 20}]
  team c: [{mary: 26}] }
```

A: None of the results below provide the structure you expect. The first option provides a dictionary to easily reference the age of a team member. To easily iterate the structure, the second option provides a dictionary of lists.

Group *users* by the attribute *team*. Create the lists of keys and values

```yaml
teams_list: "{{ users|groupby('team') }}"
teams_keys: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=0)|list }}"
teams_vals: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=1)|
                           map('json_query', '[].{key: name, value: age}')|
                           map('items2dict')|
                           list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
teams_keys:
  - team a
  - team b
  - team c

teams_vals:
  - {john: 24, sam: 18}
  - {tom: 20}
  - {mary: 26}
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
teams: "{{ dict(teams_keys|zip(teams_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
teams:
  team a: {john: 24, sam: 18}
  team b: {tom: 20}
  team c: {mary: 26}
```

This is not the structure that you expect. Note the missing brackets `[]`. Instead, this structure is very convenient to reference the age of a team member.

---

When you want to iterate the structure create lists of the attributes. For example,

```yaml
teams_vals: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=1)|
                           map('json_query', '[].[name, age]')|
                           list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
teams_vals:
  - - [john, 24]
    - [sam, 18]
  - - [tom, 20]
  - - [mary, 26]
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
teams: "{{ dict(teams_keys|zip(teams_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
team:
  team a:
    - [john, 24]
    - [sam, 18]
  team b:
    - [tom, 20]
  team c:
    - [mary, 26]
```

Also, this is not the structure that you expect. But, you can easily iterate it

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} - {{ item.1.0 }} - {{ item.1.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ teams|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: team a - john - 24
  msg: team a - sam - 18
  msg: team b - tom - 20
  msg: team c - mary - 26
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    users:
      - {age: 24, name: john, team: team a}
      - {age: 26, name: mary, team: team c}
      - {age: 18, name: sam, team: team a}
      - {age: 20, name: tom, team: team b}
    teams_list: "{{ users|groupby('team') }}"
    teams_keys: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=0)|list }}"
    teams_vals: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=1)|
                               map('json_query', '[].{key: name, value: age}')|
                               map('items2dict')|
                               list }}"
    teams_val2: "{{ teams_list|map(attribute=1)|
                               map('json_query', '[].[name, age]')|
                               list }}"
    teams: "{{ dict(teams_keys|zip(teams_vals)) }}"
    team2: "{{ dict(teams_keys|zip(teams_val2)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: teams
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} - {{ item.1.0 }} - {{ item.1.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ team2|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
- name: Variables Members
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    user_1: {'name': alan, 'age': 20}
    user_2: {'name': geofrey, 'age': 21}
    user_3: {'name': ray, 'age': 22}
    user_4: {'name': bob, 'age': 23}
    user_5: {'name': stephen, 'age': 24}
    cacheable: yes

- name: Variables Teams
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    team_a: ["{{ansible_facts.user_1}}",
             "{{ansible_facts.user_2}}",
             "{{ansible_facts.user_3}}"]
    team_b: ["{{ansible_facts.user_4}}",
             "{{ansible_facts.user_5}}"]
    cacheable: yes

- name: All Teams
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    teams: {'team a': "{{ansible_facts.team_a}}", 
            'team b': "{{ansible_facts.team_b}}"}
    cacheable: yes
```

Comment: Not really, I don't know what the team name is.  What I need to do is to retrieve the value in dictionary and group by this attribute.